# UITableView increase contentInset bottom without scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to increase tableView content bottom inset without scrolling

because I have cell which include textField, but textFields are hidden when keyboard appears

and when keyboard appears, users can scroll to bottom without dismiss keyboard

so I want to increase tableView content bottom inset without scroll when keyboard appears,

then user can scroll to bottom without dismiss keyboard

Answer (score 0):

For getting the height of the keyboard, create an observer which calls a method that gives the keyboard height, and by using this height we calculate and set the `UITableView` bottom inset.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

The below method is an observer method that will be called when the keyboard appears.

***Here I consider the height of `UITableView` is same as device height. If `UITableView` height is different from device height then you have to make changes in below code for setting up proper inset.***

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        tableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: tableview.contentInset.top, left: tableview.contentInset.left, bottom: keyboardHeight, right: tableview.contentInset.right)
    }
}
```

When the keyboard disappears then the below delegate method will be called, so we set bottom content inset to zero.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    tableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: tableview.contentInset.top, left: tableview.contentInset.left, bottom: 0.0, right: tableview.contentInset.right)
}
```